# How to notify FrontEnd whenever an aws SNS response is received in the HTTP endpoint, in my case a spring Controller?

Tags: spring, push-notification, amazon-sns

I understood that aws SNS can be configured to a HTTP endpoint. But how to trigger the notification from the endpoint to the Frontend UI. I am using Spring and a controller will define the HTTP endpoint. How should the controller send back data to UI whenever SNS topic is sent to the controller.

Comment: did you try to use websocket? Other way would be a continous polling from the front-end to the server.

Comment: Like @Angelo said you need to use websocket as continuous polling will overload the network try [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Comment: @AngeloImmediata How to integrate websocket and sns endpoints? I am currently using Server Sent events to test sending data from Server side and is working perfectly. But how to integrate it with SNS HTTP endpoints is unclear.

Comment: I guess your controller should receive the notification of a aws SNS response and generate a message to a well known topic; front-end UI must be subscribed to the topic and it should receive the generated message

Comment: try to give a look to this http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_sns_support